# Ack - why can't my .ASHX find this namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The file Mexico.Data.dll is at /bin/ and other pages references it without error, what's my problemo?

CODE:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="AuthCheck" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using Mexcio.Data;

public class AuthCheck : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        ODA.Users findMatch = new ODA.Users();
        findMatch.loadByUserName(context.Request.QueryString["uname"],"=","");

        string getPass = decrypt(findMatch[0].Password);

        if ((FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(getPass, System.Web.Configuration.FormsAuthPasswordFormat.SHA1)) == (context.Request.QueryString["pass"]))
        {
            context.Response.Write("OK");
        }

    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

ERROR:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Mexcio' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 3:  using System;
Line 4:  using System.Web;
Line 5:  using Mexcio.Data;
Line 6:  
Line 7:  public class AuthCheck : IHttpHandler {


Source File: c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\devv\services\AuthCheck.ashx    Line: 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The using statement has a typo: using **Mexcio**.Data; should be using **Mexico**.Data;

Comment: Don't worry, I've been there many times!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem, but it wasn't a simple typo.  Here is how I solved it:

`Mexico.Data` is a custom defined namespace that should also be in the GAC. Add the following string to the top of your ashx file.

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Mexico.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234567890" %>
```

Change the `PublicKeyToken` and `Version` to match, and you should be able to use `Mexico.Data` (or your own dll) in your ashx.